# python elasticsearch get field from given doc_id

Tags: elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

My input is <index_name>, <doc_id>, <field_name>, i want the value of the field

I am looking for python-client equivalent of

```
GET <index_name>/_doc/<doc_id>/?_source_includes=<field_name>
```

Comment: Question doesn't show any sign of effort on your part.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
result = es.get(
             index=<index_name>,
             id=<doc_id>,
             _source_includes=<field_name>
         )
```